# How do I write vim-latex like custom key bindings into the Overleaf (Codemirror) editor?

Tags: vim, tampermonkey, userscripts, codemirror, overleaf

I am aware that Tampermonkey (https://www.tampermonkey.net/) could potentially do this. I installed a Tampermonkey chrome extension, and under "Dashboard", I added the following userscript (All the commented-out lines I tried below <<    CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("jj", "", "insert");>> didn't work).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Overleaf Editor Custom VIM Keybindings
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://www.overleaf.com/project/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
'use strict';

window.addEventListener("UNSTABLE_editor:extensions", (event) => {
const { CodeMirror, CodeMirrorVim, extensions } = event.detail;

// add custom keybindings - insert mode applies on insert
CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("jj", "<Esc>", "insert");
//    CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("kk", "Right-Right", "insert");
//    CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("ECI", "\\cite{<++>}<++>", "insert");
//    CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("aa", "<Down>", "insert");
//    CodeMirrorVim.Vim.imap("`a", "\alpha", "insert");
//    CodeMirrorVim.IMAP('FMB', "\\mathbb{<++>}<++>", 'insert')

// normal mode applies while escaped
// CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("h", "j", "normal");
//    CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("hh", "<Right>", "normal");
});
})();
```

```
    CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("jj", "<Esc>", "insert");
```

works but

```
CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("kk", "<Right>", "insert");
CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("kk", "Right-Right", "insert");
CodeMirrorVim.Vim.map("kk", "<Esc>-<Right>", "insert");
```

all didn't work. So how do I write, for example, the following bindings in 'tex.vim" in Tampermonkey userscript?

Here is keybindings in my "tex.vim":

```
call IMAP  ('FTX', "\\text{<++>}<++>", 'tex')
call IMAP  ('FCA', "\\mathcal{<++>}<++>", 'tex')
call IMAP  ('EBM', "\\begin{bmatrix}\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{bmatrix}", 'tex')
imap kk <C-j>
```

Also it would be nice if we could input greeks in overleaf CodeMirror editor as we do using vim-latex:
typing "`a" gives "\alpha".

Comment: I'm confused as to where the userscript runs. Can you [edit] your post to include the URL of the page the script is running or at least the relevant part of the site's HTML?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original post, hopefully it is better now.

Comment: Might be a good idea to [raise an issue](https://github.com/replit/codemirror-vim/issues/new) in the codemirror-vim plugin repo.

Comment: Right. I will do that.